# Copiar una subcadena del campo de una tabla a otro campo de la misma tabla en PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una base de datos con una tabla de varios millones de registros. Los registros se encuentran en la tabla *padron_afip*, columna o campo llamado *conjunto* y cada registro de campo tiene 52 caracteres en total,  representan el conjunto de datos de inscritos del padrón. Los primeros 11 caracteres corresponden a un identificador único llamado CUIT, del 12 al 41 se encuentra la cadena que representa el nombre o denominación y así hasta completar los 52 caracteres. Dejo una lista que muestra la secuencia de toda la cadena como referencia.

| Nombre | Posición | Longitud |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CUIT | 1 / 11 | 11 |
| DENOMINACION | 12 / 41 | 30 |
| IMP GANANCIAS | 42 / 43 | 2 |
| IMP IVA | 44 / 45 | 2 |
| MONOTRIBUTO | 46 / 47 | 2 |
| INTEGRANTE SOC | 48 | 1 |
| EMPLEADOR | 49 | 1 |
| ACTIVIDAD MONOTRIBUTO | 51 / 52 | 2 |

Lo que busco es separar los datos del campo *conjunto* en 8 campos diferentes `(CUIT, DENOMINACION, IMP GANANCIAS, IMP_IVA, MONOTRIBUTO, INTEGRANTE, EMPLEADOR, ACTIVIDAD_MONOTRIBUTO)`

Intenté copiar el CUIT en la misma tabla usando el siguiente script y por alguna razón corrió pero el contenido no se copio en la columna CUIT.

El script que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```sql
SELECT*FROM padron_afip
insert into padron_afip(cuit)
SELECT substring(conjunto , 1, 11) as id FROM padron_afip;
```

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. _Intenté copiar el CUIT en la misma tabla usando el siguiente script y por alguna razón corrió pero el contenido no se copio en la columna CUIT_: ¿se _commitearon_ los cambios?

Comment: Hola @padaleiana, muchas gracias por contestar, te comento que no hice commit de los cambios, estoy utilizando dbeaver-ce para trabajar con bases de datos. ¿Dónde podré ver si el gestor de de BDs lo hizo?

Comment: Para la herramienta DBeaver, en la [documentación](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Auto-and-Manual-Commit-Modes/) se explica cuándo está activo el commit automático y el manual. Revísalo. ¡No olvides que la documentación es tu mejor aliada!

Comment: ¡Entonces ponlo como respuesta! Y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. No olvides que es [es.so] es un sitio de _preguntas y respuestas_. De nuevo: haz el [tour] para conocer cómo funciona. Como verás, el código es ilegible en los comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Resolví el problema, no necesitaba usar *INSERT*, lo que estaba haciendo es insertar mas filas y lo que necesitaba era modificarlas. Utilicé la sentencia *UPDATE *de la siguiente manera:

```
UPDATE public.padron_afip
SET cuit=substring(conjunto , 1, 11), denominacion=substring(conjunto , 12, 30), ganancias=substring(conjunto , 42, 2), iva=substring(conjunto , 44, 2), monotributo=substring(conjunto , 46, 2), sociedades=substring(conjunto , 48, 1), empleador=substring(conjunto , 49, 1), actividad=substring(conjunto , 50, 2);
```

Gracias @padalelana por la ayuda.

Comment: Para darle formato a tu consulta, agrega triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después del mismo. Soy _padaleiana_, por cierto :)